# How to call an async method to create a file on application start up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, server.mappath, application-start

I want to create an Asp MVC application to run a code every 12 hours. This code will **create a file** on the server each time.

So I've made an async method and called it from `Application_Start` event to make a schedule and It worked fine.

My problem is where I want to **create the file**. As I call my method from `Application_Start`, the instance of `Server.MapPath` is not available there. So I moved my calling code into `Application_AuthenticateRequest`. But the problem was still here, this time because of my async method that doesn't allow using the `Server.MapPath`.

What is the solution to do all of these in MVC.net:

1. Create a method which is called every 12 hours
2. Create async method to avoid locking application on
   application_start
3. Create a file on each call

Comment: Why not create a windows service? you can easily create a schedule for the service.

Comment: @Nkosi Because my server is a shared server and I have not access to windows service

Comment: You can make a thread in  application_start that calls a service or api every 12 hours and that api/service maps the File to the server

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada I think it will work by your solution. However, I should make a separate project for this. If I can't find better one, I will use this. Thanks

Comment: MVC is the completely wrong way to do this. At best it will be unreliable. Can you use Azure Functions? If you are calling it only every 12 hours the entire thing would probably  be completely free.